# Document Library - Want Duplicate Report Names

Tags: 2007, document-library, duplicate

In a document library that lists reports (in PDFs), I have a column for the fiscal year and period, and for these reports that run every month I would like to name them the same, but can't.  Also, I'd like to be able to click on the report's name to open the PDF.

There are three different kinds of Name columns, but I can't seem to use any of them for this purpose.  Am I missing something or is there a workarond?

Otherwise, I will be stuck with adding the fiscal year and period (or month) on each report's name.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can only place your reports into folders (one folder per year). Otherwise you cannot have files with the same name on the same level (folder) of a document library.

This is the same rule as for the file system: you cannot have files with the same file name in the same folder.

Comment: I can see the logic in it (same for duplicate file names in a folder).  I'm just trying to make it look as simple as possible.  But adding other text to each report name just makes it look more complicated, that's all.  Anyway, thanks for your reply.